# Implement and editable label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to present a user with a normal screen with a few fields (Description, Date etc). But I would like them to click the label and without a postback (visible) the label becomes editable, and a 'Save' button appears somewhere.

Once they click save, the data gets saved, and the edit boxes turn back into labels.

Is there a way to implement this?

ASP.Net being used.

Comment: You may try UpdatePanel and FormView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few [edit in place plugins for jQuery](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20edit%20in%20place).  Using one will help you get up and running quickly.

[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) is one of the more mature and popular of such plugins.  You can find [help specifically for using Jeditable with ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249928/224087).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use an edit box, and toggle either readonly or enabled?

Comment: this should've been a comment (IMHO). Replying to your post: this is a known UI paradigm, 'edit in place'. I find it much more comfortable than readonly text inputs.